# Packing sets to maximize overlap

Tags: reductions, np-hard, packing

We are given a set of $m$ elements $\{e_1,...,e_m\}$ that form our universe $\mathcal{U}$. Each element of our universe is further associated with a positive weight $w(e_j)$ with $j\in \{1,...m\}$. We are further given a collection $S=\{S_1,...S_n\}$ of subsets of  $\mathcal{U}$ whose union equals the universe. The intersection of any two sets in $S$ may be non-empty (i.e. subsets may overlap with each other).

Furthermore,

1) we are given an infinite number of configurations; each configuration can host up to $k$ subsets from $S$. There is no cost for using a configuration.

2) When assigning 2 or more subsets to one configuration and there is an overlap between the sets (i.e. an element is part of more than one set) **we pay the weight of that element only once**. Obviously, there can be no overlap between subsets when considering different configurations.

**Objective:**

we want to assign each subset of $S$ to exactly one configuration in such a way that the weighted sum of the elements over all configurations is minimized. Consider the following example:

$\mathcal{U}=\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g\}$,

$w(a)=2$

$w(b)=2$

$w(c)=3$

$w(d)=4$

$w(e)=1$

$w(f)=2$

$w(g)=2$

$S=\{S_1, S_2, S_3\},$

$S_1=\{a,b,c\}, S_2=\{c,d,e\}, S_2=\{e,f,g\}$

$k=2$

In this case, since $k<|S|$, it is obvious that more than one configurations are needed. Moreover,  $S_1$ and $S_2$ should be packed together in the same configuration because of their heavy overlap ($S_1 \cap S_2$ gives the biggest overlap in our example - we pay 3 less cost units). So, the total cost of such an assignment is 12+5=17 and 2 configurations are needed.

Any ideas on how to prove that the problem is indeed intractable? Any ideas on how to calculate a good bound on the number of configurations that are needed?

The unweighted version (when the weights of the elements are all 1) is also very interesting to me. However, I did not manage to find something so far in the literature also for this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're trying to solve. What objects are weighted? What does it mean to minimize "in multiple configurations"? When $|S|=10$ and $k=4$, why are there three configurations? Whatever all those things mean, isn't the problem exactly the classical set cover problem when you set all the weights equal to 1 and have only one configuration? If set cover really is a special case, and your problem is still in NP (which should be trivial to prove), then your problem is automatically NP-complete.

Comment: Please give an example. As stated, your problem is hard to understand. Also, as David mentions, perhaps the best you can do is use approximation algorithms or heuristics.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I tried to come up with a better description of my problem. Hope that the new description is much clearer.

Comment: [cross posted](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/34182/) on [cstheory.se].

Answer (score 1):

When $k=1$, the problem is trivial: the optimal solution is to put each set in its own configuration.

When $k=2$, the problem can be solved in polynomial time using graph matching.  Build a complete undirected graph with one vertex per set.  The cost of the edge $(S_i,S_j)$ is the cost of putting $S$ and $T$ together in the same configuration (i.e., the weight of $S_i \cup S_j$).  Now the optimal solution to your problem is given by the minimum-cost perfect matching in this graph.  That matching can be [computed in polynomial time using standard algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#In_general_graphs).

When $k=3$, the problem is NP-hard.  In fact, it is NP-hard to determine whether a graph can be covered by a disjoint union of cycles of length $\le 3$ (i.e., whether you can find a set of cycles, where each cycle has length 2 or 3, where no two cycles have any vertex in common, and where every vertex appears in one of these cycles).  This implies that your problem is intractible when $k\ge 3$.

The proof of the hardness result I alluded to can be found in Section 3 of the following paper:

[Clearing Algorithms for Barter Exchange Markets: Enabling Nationwide Kidney Exchanges](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sandholm/kidneyExchange.EC07.withGrantInfo.pdf).  David J Abraham, Avrim Blum, Tuomas Sandholm. EC 2007.

That said, not all hope is lost.  There are techniques available for finding a solution that will be close to optimal, using integer linear programming.  For instance, you can express your problem as an instance of integer linear programming and then apply an off-the-shelf ILP solver.  See the paper above for some more sophisticated techniques that might be applicable in your situation as well.