# Partition a family of sets to maximize cumulative overlap and cardinality

Tags: np-hard, polynomial-time-reductions

My problem is this: I have a list of $n$ items $N$ (think of them as the natural numbers $1,\dots,n$) and $m$ subsets of $N$ $S_1,\dots,S_m$ which may overlap. The objective is to find a partition of the $m$ subsets $(P_1,\dots,P_k)$ for any $1\leq k\leq m$ maximising the following quantity
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k\left|\bigcap_{S_j\in P_i}S_j\right|\cdot (|P_i|-1)
$$
i.e. I want to maximise the sum of the overlap of the sets within each component of the partition, multiplied with the number of sets in that component minus 1.

I want to show that this problem is NP-hard or I want a polynomial time algorithm solving it. The closest problem I have found is [this one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/55037/packing-sets-to-maximize-overlap) but it is not quite what I need. I would appreciate any help, including suggestions for problems I may be able to reduce from.

Thank you!

Comment: The special case where all $P$'s are limited to be size 2 can be solved by finding a maximum matching in a suitable undirected graph, and the special case where all $P$'s are limited to be size 3 is NP-hard by reduction from [3-dimensional matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching) (have one set $S_j$ per vertex in the graph, containing all hyper-edges incident on that vertex), but I don't know what the complexity of the general problem might be.

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If all of your subsets $\mathcal{S}=S_1,\dots,S_m$ have exactly two elements, then this family is effectively a graph $G$ with vertex set $N$ and edge set $\mathcal{S}$ (and $|\mathcal{S}|=m,|N|=n$). Now, you can prove that there exists a partition of $\mathcal{S}$ for which your objective function yields at least the value $m-k$ (for some $k<n$) if and only if $G$ admits a vertex cover of size at most $k$. As Vertex Cover is NP-hard, so must this problem be, even in this restricted setting.

Comment: Thank you so much! that is really helpful