# How to show that my problem cannot be approximated within a certain factor unless P=NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, approximation

Before I introduce my problem I need to define a couple of things. Suppose we have two sets $S_1=\{1,2,3\}$ and $S_2=\{2,3,4\}$. A *compression tree* for $S_1$ and $S_2$ is

```
   {2,3}
    / \
   /   \
  {1}  {4}
```

i.e. the left leaf is associated with $S_1$ and has the property that the union of the sets in a leaf-to-root path yields $S_1$. This generalizes to any number of sets, and a compression tree is allowed to have any depth and the internal nodes are allowed any degree. The cost of a compression tree is the cumulative size of the sets in its nodes (so the above tree has cost 4). A *compression forest* for the sets $S_1,\dots,S_m$ is a set of (disjoint) compression trees where each set occurs in exactly one leaf.

I have the following problem. Given a family of subsets $S_1,\dots,S_m$ of $S=\{1,\dots,n\}$ I want to find a compression forest of minimal cost. I have shown this problem to be NP-complete by reduction from vertex cover (thanks to the suggestion in [this thread](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/159224/partition-a-family-of-sets-to-maximize-cumulative-overlap-and-cardinality)).

I want to show that it cannot be approximated within some factor (e.g. constant, $O(\log n)$ or $O(\log m)$), or not at all, unless P=NP (I dont know that this is the case but the problem feels 'hard' enough). I have tried to show that an approximation algorithm for my problem can solve weighted vertex cover or TSP but to no avail. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or inspiration you may be able  to provide.

Thanks!

Comment: A general approach is to find an (approximation-preserving) reduction from some NP-complete problem that is hard to approximate.  Vertex cover is easy to approximate, but perhaps you can reduce from some other problem that is hard to approximate.

Comment: that is a good suggestion, thanks!